# Visual Studio debugger doesn't recognize any usings

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

When I'm debugging in Visual Studio, I can no longer evaluate any static that isn't fully qualified. Hovering over the field, the watch window, and the immediate window all are broken.

I get the error `the name ___ does not exist in the current context`.

I can fix it if I specify the full namespace in the watch, but this can't work for extensions methods or if I just want to hover over the item in code.

It's like the debugger no longer sees any of the `usings` that are in the current context. Every now and then it will work, but most of the time I have to type the full namespace for the debugger to find whatever I want to evaluate.

I was hoping VS2015 would fix it, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Super late reply, but as of sometime around the beginning of 2018 Fody no longer causes this problem. It was a Cecil issue and that was fixed with Cecil 0.10.

Answer (score 0):

This was due to Fody. We stopped using Fody and it fixed the issue.